# howto find which recipe provides a RPM (or DEB or IPK) package?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

(in this question I talk RPM but the same issue concerns DEB and IPK I suppose)

How can I find which recipe provides a given RPM package? Is there a tool for that?
With `grep` and looking at the source code of the recipes, I can find out, but it is tedious.

Moreover the package name in yocto is not always the same as the RPM package name. Is there a tool for showing the relationship?

Examples:

- which recipe provides the RPM package libgmp10? (and what is the PACKAGE name in yocto)
- same question for the RPM package libmount1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those packages are already built, you can use the `oe-pkgdata-util` tool to find which recipe that provides a certain package. It's agnostic to which package format you're using, so it works for rpm/deb/ipk.

In the example below I want to find out which recipe that provides the package called `libmount1`, and the command shows that the recipe name is `util-linux`

```
$ oe-pkgdata-util lookup-recipe libmount1
util-linux
```

And to find the recipe-space package name:

```
$ oe-pkgdata-util lookup-pkg -r libmount1
util-linux-libmount
```